# css box shadow, not working when parent div has background

Tags: html, css

I am having a trouble, I am trying to put curved shadow for my box, its showing correctly, but if I put a background color to the parent element, it will not show.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfy4ss3p/).

Please have a look, try to remove the background-color of '`.parent`', you can see what i am trying to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the shadow has a z-index of -1, which means that the parent div will be in front of the shadow. So if the parent has a non-transparent background, it will cover the shadow. You should assign a z-index smaller than -1 to the parent.

```
.parent{background-color:#eee; position:relative; width:100%; height:300px; z-index: -2}
```

Comment: WOw... thats what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow is under the `.parent` element (due to negative z-index). Then, if you put background to element in higher level, it's normal that you see just this background.

Put the parent under the shadow, it'll work.

```
.parent {z-index: -2}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfy4ss3p/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent
{
z-index:0;
}
```

[Check Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfy4ss3p/3/%5C)

Answer (score 0):

Its working while removing background on parent http://prntscr.com/6cwlkj